# Is there a Windows API memory allocator/deallocator I can use that will just give me an error code if something goes wrong & in a cross-compiler way?

Tags: c, winapi, memory-management

This is probably a crazy question but:

For the purposes of debugging and error handling I'd like to be able to make a note of *why* an allocation or free call failed. I'd like the same code to be compilable by both Microsoft's C compilers and MinGW-w64 (but not other MinGWs).

I could use `malloc()`/`realloc()`/`free()` but they don't provide any defined method of getting an error other than `ENOMEM`. Or is it safe to assume that the *only* reason `malloc()` can fail is lack of memory, which `HeapAlloc()` and others seems to disagree with? (This will also stop being an option if I choose not to use the C runtime in any future DLLs.) Or is it safe to assume that `errno` has any other error code? I would need to check my standards again...

I could also use `HeapAlloc()`/`HeapReAlloc()`/`HeapFree()`, but they don't return a last-error code. Instead, they can be made to throw an exception, which you are supposed to catch with a `__try` block... which is not supported by MinGW. libseh is not an option here; my programs and DLLs should be freestanding. I'm going to assume it is *not* safe to assume that the only reason it can fail when set to not throw an exception is out of memory because heap corruption is listed as a possibility; is this correct?

I tried using `LocalAlloc()`/`LocalReAlloc()`/`LocalFree()` but it failed to allocate more than a 256-byte-or-so structure and 2 `int`s, returning `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`.

There's no `VirtualReAlloc()`, so I assume I would need to write my own `malloc()` implementation if I go the `VirtualAlloc()` route.

Or am I just being crazy about all this?

And what about other allocators that I would be required to use, such as `SysAllocString()`; would it be safe to assume those can only ever fail because of out of memory?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use `malloc` ... I guess that when `malloc` fails to get memory from the OS, it is setting `errno` to `ENOMEM` (whatever the OS failure is)

Comment: Crazy or not, I don't understand the question. What extra information would you expect from a `malloc` error code? Either there is a big enough block of memory to accomodate your request, or there isn't. It might be due to fragmentation, but you will never get a portable detailled report on the memory allocator state.

Comment: The sum of all possible errors is the sum of all error conditions documented for the functions in question. So what?

Comment: If the heap is corrupted, something else already got wrong; and the best you can do when you detect this, is to crash. Some C libraries do this in some cases (glibc, for example, and apparently, Microsoft's also detects some of them). In either case, such errors cannot be caught reliably and should never happen at all.

Comment: @kuroineko I'm not interested in an operating system-portable solution. If something depends on the behavior of Microsoft's implementation, as long as that's documented, that's fine. Most of my paranoia admittedly stems from the fact that `HeapAlloc()` says it can return a condition on heap corruption.

Comment: @mafso in that case I'm going to assume the only *reliable* reason for an allocation failure is out of memory, correct?

Comment: @andlabs; Yes. Everything else indicates a bug somewhere else.

Comment: In that case for now I'll just use `malloc()` and `free()` and assume that the only failure (`NULL` return) is out of memory. Thanks! I'll leave this question open in the meantime, as I wonder what I should do with `HeapFree()` should I need to NOT use the C runtime at some point in the future.